# Is there a way to not rescue in test environment in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

```
begin
  ...
rescue => e
  puts "Error: #{ e } at: \n#{ e.backtrace.first }"
end
```

This works pretty well, but sometimes the error is reported to be in rack test. This makes it difficult to figure out where the error is coming from.

So, I would like to disable the rescue clause when running in the test environment.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
rescue => e
  if Rails.env.test?
    raise
  else
    puts "Error: #{ e } at: \n#{ e.backtrace.first }"
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree. I don't think the rescue should be there in the first place. But this is the only way to do what you are asking for.

Comment: @BSeven why exactly do yo do the rescue in production/development. I might suggest some other approach.

Comment: It is for a mailer. In production, if the mailer fails, I want to write to the log. In test environment, if it fails then I would like the normal error message.

Comment: In rails 4.2 we can use `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404` in controllers (not sure about earlier versions).